# Off-topic -> migration dialog only offers emacs-meta as an alternative

Tags: support, migration, vote-to-close

Noticed this morning that voting to close a question via `closing -> off-topic -> migration`, the only site I can select as the appropriate migration destination is emacs meta. I think this used to provide a few common options as well as a text-entry box or 'other' category?

Pretty sure migrating to meta is not something we want to happen in most cases!

Answer (score 1):

The migration dialog offers meta on all Stack Exchange sites. That's because some users aren't aware that meta exists and post meta questions on the only site they know, which is the main site.

Other sites may be offered but they have to be activated by Stack Exchange sites. This would only be done for sites that we often migrate to. In the 2½-year history of the site, we've only migrated 12 questions¹, so no site comes close to being worth adding to the list.

There has never been a write-in option in the migration dialog. You may be confusing it with the close → off-topic dialog, which does have a write-in option.

If you think a question should be migrated, vote to close as off-topic, and *flag* it. Moderators can migrate a question to any site. But the question has to be less than 60 days old. Note that questions are only migrated if they meet all of the following criteria:

- Off-topic here.
- On-topic on the proposed site.
- Sufficient quality so that it wouldn't be closed on the target site. Note that the question must be ok in its current state. If the question needs additional information from the asker, just vote to close and suggest that the asker reposts.

¹  <sub>You can see this information under the [migrated tab of `/tools`](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tools/posts/migrated/away). To access `/tools`, click “review” and select the “Tools” tab. This requires 10k reputation.</sub>

Comment: The question that motivated this was on-topic for unix.stackexchange.com, as it dealt with the desktop manager intercepting keystrokes. It has since been closed.

Comment: I follow your logic, but it still seems odd that the *only* choice for 'migration' is meta. That is, if a question should be migrated, it would make sense to offer 'meta' and 'other' as options. As is, if a question doesn't belong on meta, the migration option doesn't apply at all. Which may contribute to the small number of questions that end up getting migrated.

Comment: @Tyler Which question is that? If it's less than 60 days old, is answerable and hasn't been reposted, a moderator can migrate it.

Comment: I left a comment on the question, but I can't find the comment in my activities list, which I think means the question may have been deleted? I'm not sure. This is ultimately a pretty trivial issue, sorry to be taking your time with it :/

Comment: @Tyler https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/34403/how-to-give-emacs-the-control-of-keyboard-at-startup (since then deleted by the asker). It wouldn't be migratable in its current state, because it has no information about the environment. The asker left a comment with the required information, and the question would be ok to migrate if this information was edited into the question. But now that the asker has deleted, it's up to them to repost if they wish.